# When contacts are merged, how does Pidgin choose to which one to send a message?

Tags: pidgin

When contacts are merged, how does Pidgin choose to which one to send a message?

Comment: The one that is currently online? Wild guess.

Comment: @Thiago that too, but I mean when more than one are online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click, and click "expand".  It selects the first one in the list of merged contacts.  You can reorder them so that it sends the message where you want it to be sent.

Logical order in a contact is important but the actual choice is more complicated than just that (and is in the [pidgin FAQ](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#IgroupedmybuddiesintocontactscanIcontrolwhichoneisselected)).

Answer (score 0):

I keep the contact names same and display the protocol icons to avoid the confusion. It would have been better if there was always an option to keep the merged contacts expanded.